# How do I assign a modifier to all objects using the same material

Tags: materials, modifiers, objects, 3d-view, workflow

How do I apply a displace modifier to all objects using the same material without selecting every object one at a time that uses that material and adding a modifier to each?

Details: Since 1 material requires all the same modifier I thought maybe I could use the node editor to apply it but don't know how if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to select each object, ensuring that the *last object selected* is the one with the modifier on it.Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>>*modifiers* to link all modifiers to the selected objects. [image]

Comment: I did it wrong but it still worked.
I selected all the shapes that didn't have a modifier that I wanted to apply a modifier, I assigned a modifier but nothing happened until I did CTRL+L over the selected shapes and choose modifier then it applied.

Comment: OP stated they didn't want to have to select each object one at a time, yet that is what is done in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

With the object with the material and modifier as the active object, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select 'Materials'. this will select all objects that share the material. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select 'Modifiers'. This will give all the objects the same modifiers.

Note: If you want to make a change to the modifier and have the change across all the objects, you will have to select them all again and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while making the change.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: you can assign a single object a material, and then select all your other objects and reselect the original one last holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to link the material to all the others. The same can be done for a modifier, and anything else you see in that list.

This is as simple as I can answer since I am not sure of how you actually have the modifier and material linked together.